# how to download inta profile by python

Tags: python, pip, instaloader

I wanted to download an insta profile picture so I used this code

```
import instaloader

ig = instaloader.instaloader()
dp = input("insta user name :"  )
ig.download_profile(dp , profile_pic_only=true)
```

but I faced this erorr:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/m.h.gh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/1.py", line 1, in
>
> import instaloader
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instaloader'

Then I wrote this code

```
pip3 install instaloader
```

and faced:

> SyntaxError:   invalid syntax

I'm using python 3.8.

Comment: Please put more effort into your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 1):

The command `pip3 install instaloader` needs to be run in a commandline, not inside your python script.

Comment: It helps to explain that 'pip' is a standalone executable that goes alongside 'python'

Comment: i did it also in command line but didnt work again